# Fo-dicom How I can Call My Output.dcm file In Main

Tags: fo-dicom

Im New In Fo-Dicom , Im Trying To Call My output.dcm file in Dicom Dump ,
Im Trying to add private tags using fo-dicom

```
        string filename = "output.dcm";
        DicomDataset ds = new DicomDataset(); //Main dataset
        ds.Add(DicomTag.SpecificCharacterSet, txtCharacherSet.Text);    
        //Add some items
        ds.Add(DicomTag.PatientID, txtid.Text);
        ds.Add(DicomTag.PatientName, txtname.Text);
        DicomDataset sqContent = new DicomDataset();                
        //Content of the sequence
        sqContent.Add(DicomTag.Modality, txtModality.Text);
        sqContent.Add(DicomTag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate, 
        DateTime.Now.Date);
        DicomSequence sq = new 
        DicomSequence(DicomTag.ScheduledProcedureStepSequence, sqContent); 
       // Create sequence, add content
        ds.Add(sq); //Add sequence to main dataset
        DicomFile file = new DicomFile();
        file.Dataset.Add(ds); //Add main dataset to DicomFile
        file.FileMetaInfo.TransferSyntax = 
        DicomTransferSyntax.ImplicitVRLittleEndian;                  
       //Specify transfer syntax
        file.Save(filename); //Save file to disk
```

This Code Is Working Well , But My Private Tags Are Not Showing In Display form.

Comment: Anyone Help me . Is Im Going Wrong ..How Can I call This Output.dcm file in my main function

Comment: Im Using Fo-Dicom . I have Created My Private Tage in My Dcm File . i trying to open these tags in main dicom file .

This Is My Main Header [Main Header Of Dicom Image][1] 
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC89y.png

And This my Private Tags Header[Private Tags Header Generated By Fo-Dicom][2]

    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zCxR.png

How Can I Merge Them Into a Single Header File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understand correctly what you want to do. But as I see this you would like to anonymize a dataset, that means you want to write your own values into the default public dicom tags (private tags is a term defined in DICOM and do mean tags that are not defined within the DICOM standard).

I would recommend you to do the following: First open the first file

```
DicomDataset ds = DicomFile.Read("input1.dcm").Dataset;
```

instead of creating a complete new DicomDataset instance.
Then add all the information from the second header:

```
ds.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.PatientId, txtid.Text);
...
```

The AddOrUpdate adds the DicomTag if it does not already exist or replaces it with the new value if it has existed.

Comment: thanks for your response. i have already add my private tags in a separate file.The problem is that i need to open these tags in my main file . private tags that generated by code are saved into a separate file. i want to merge both file . in my code i have used                                       file.FileMetaInfo.TransferSyntax = 
        DicomTransferSyntax.ImplicitVRLittleEndian;     i think this code not work correctly